# Finding xpath using tr/td

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php
Find xpath for first name and last name is very difficult. How Xpath can be used if
there is no id , tag or class available.

**Contact 
              Information**

```
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td align="right"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b>First 
          Name: </b></font></td>
        <td> 
          <input maxlength="60" name="firstName" size="20">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td align="right"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><b>Last 
          Name: </b></font></td>

        <td> 
          <input maxlength="60" name="lastName" size="20">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select both of those elements by their name attribute.

```
//input[@name='firstName']
```

and

```
//input[@name='lastName']
```

If you are using java (you don't mention your language) and you have a WebDriver defined as "driver" you could use either:

```
WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']"));
```

or alternatively you could look it up specifically by name:

```
WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.name("firstName"));
```